# How do I know which display card my laptop is using

Tags: 16.04, display

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell laptop.

When I run `lspci | grep VGA` I get the following output:

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M]
```

How do I know which display card my laptop is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in which graphics the X display is using, first get the graphics drivers on the system:

```
lshw -c video
```

and search for those drivers in /var/log/xorg.0.log:

```
grep -i i915 /var/log/xorg.0.log
```

Also the driver should be found in /etc/X11/xorg.conf in the screen section (if that file is present).